# To What Extent Can One Rely on Writing to Disk When SIGTERM is Given?

Tags: linux, daemon, dbus, systemd, sigterm

I am developing for Linux and have a daemon that should write to disk when it is killed. The daemon could be configured to listen to `SIGTERM` and write to disk when that signal is received.

I am also familiar with the `PrepareForShutdown` D-Bus signal issued by the [login manager](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/). Listening to `SIGTERM` results in simpler code than inhibiting shutdown and listening to the `PrepareForShutdown` signal. Another advantage of `SIGTERM` is that it handles cases where the daemon is politely killed even though the system shuts down.

However, I am not sure how safe it is to rely on the `SIGTERM` signal being sent by the kernel at shutdown. At shutdown is `SIGTERM` always sent to every process with enough time to perform a small (< 1 kB) write to disk?

One concern I have is that I might have enough time to write to disk on some hardware but not on others, so it seems difficult to test. The same could be said of the `PrepareForShutdown` signal, but at least allowing enough time for disk writes is part of the contract of that signal. My question is whether the same can be said for the `SIGTERM` signal every process receives on shutdown.

Comment: Why is that a concern? It can be viewed more as a sysadmin issue than as a coding issue!

Comment: There is no sysadmin, so it is my concern regardless of whether it's coding issue or not.

Comment: Then what is the actual platform? Some embedded Linux thing? With what kind of disk and filesystem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) - so you can't `fprintf` from a signal handler. Often the most sensible thing to do is to set some `volatile sigatomic_t` variable in the signal handler, and test that variable outside it.

The point is not only to [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) some data to a file system. It is to get the data written to the disk (it might stay in kernel filesystem buffers). Read [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) & [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html).

You cannot (in all cases) be sure that data is written to the disk (especially on power outage).

I would not bother and use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) (i.e. have my `SIGTERM` handler set a `volatile sigatomic_t` flag, and later test that flag elsewhere; on termination call `syslog`...). Then document that your program is writing to the system log on termination, and leave the responsability of ensuring that the system log is written (to some disk somewhere, perhaps on the network) to the sysadmin.

The concrete behavior of shutdown is mostly a sysadmin issue. It really depends upon the actual system (including linux distribution and hardware) and the sysadmin's skills. Some file systems are remote or (for cheap USB keys) very slow file systems (and writing to them *can* be lost).

Imagine also a system with a buggy daemon (not yours but something else) which take ages to terminate. Then your daemon might not have time to do something sensible. So you have to trust the sysadmin.

I don't understand why you are asking your question. It depends upon how the entire system is administrated and set up. It really is different on million dollars servers and on a laptop.

Comment: The point of my question was to determine whether having time to write to disk depends on how the entire system is setup. Your answer speaks to this, so thank you.