# How to use a signal handler in Unix?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I am learning about signals. In the following code, how can I keep printing the prompt inside the while loop after the CTRL-C signal has been entered. Also how to terminate the process with the CTRL-D signal.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  

    struct sigaction sh;
    sh.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sh.sa_mask);
    sh.sa_flags = 0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sh, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Some prompt: ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code (e.g. the `sigint_handler()` function), and you also need to use less code (use `int main(void)` since you don't pay any attention to `argc` or `argv`).  Don't forget that by default, standard output will be line-buffered.  That means you won't see the prompt until the buffer is filled.

Comment: And also do a search. There a quite a few existing questions on how to ignore and handle signals. There is even a question that is almost identical to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485028/signal-handling-in-c.

Comment: Note what is discussed in [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/) — and maybe [What is the difference between `signal()` and `sigaction()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231912/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Signal Handling in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485028/signal-handling-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

> How to use signal handler in unix?

Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and most  importantly  [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). Use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) appropriately, since [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is buffered.

> Also how to terminate the process with the CTRL-D signal.

But <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd> is not a signal. See [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html). It triggers the end of file condition on `stdin` when that is a terminal. See [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) and [pty(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). To detect that end of file condition, see [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902364/841108) answer.

You might be interested in using [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html).

You should read a good book, such as [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) (it explains signals very well) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

Linux has [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), more friendly with [event loops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) since usable with multiplexing syscalls such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).